# Javascript Changing Firefox Proxy

Tags: javascript, firefox, proxy, imacros

I am trying to do what the title says and have been searching on here for a while now and I found a solution which looks viable. Only issue is the `requre()` function is not recognized. Now I am unsure, do I need to update java, firefox, or iMacros to fix this. As well I am not sure if I made an error in my code. For the code to follow know that there is an object for the proxies that separates proxy from port.

```
var scope = {};
Components.utils.import("resource://imacros/utils.js", scope);
Components.utils.import("resource://imacros/rijndael.js", scope);
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/ctypes.jsm", scope);

    var prefsvc = require("sdk/preferences/service");
    prefsvc.set("network.proxy.http", proxy[j].ip);
    prefsvc.set("network.proxy.http_port", proxy[j].port);
    prefsvc.set("network.proxy.type", 1);
```

What do you guys think the problem could be?

Comment: You can do this in different way. You can put proxy:port in txt file, load into iMAcros JavaScript and use PROXY iMacros command. http://wiki.imacros.net/PROXY

Comment: That was my first attempt at setting the proxy. If you use iimPlay(proxy) they proxy is only changed while you are in that block of iMacro code. My program runs multiple blocks of iMacro code, between which there is some javascript code run, while the js is running the proxy sets back to default. I need the proxy to be set and to persist until changed again.

Comment: So use iimSet("proxy",proxy) and put that code in each block. And you will have a working code.

Comment: yes, that was what I did, but once then imacro code finished executing some javascript would execute and the ip would reset to default. The website I am using this for would then detect that and stop me from performing certain actions.

Comment: @Michael Miner did you solve it? Having the same issue.

Comment: @whitesiroi unfortunately I have not. I started using better tools like selenium, however I have not tried proxies there yet

Comment: @Michael Miner Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
var macro1;

macro1 ="CODE:";
macro1 +="PROXY ADDRESS={{proxy}}";

var macro2;

macro2 ="CODE:";
macro2 +="PROXY ADDRESS={{proxy}}";

var macro1;

macro1 ="CODE:";
macro1 +="PROXY ADDRESS={{proxy}}";

var macro3;

macro3="CODE:";
macro3+="PROXY ADDRESS={{proxy}}";

iimSet("proxy","1.1.1.1:8000")
iimPlay(macro1)

iimSet("proxy","1.1.1.1:8000")
iimPlay(macro2)

iimSet("proxy","1.1.1.1:8000")
iimPlay(macro3)
```

Edit:

```
var mainmacro;

mainmacro ="CODE:";
mainmacro +="PROXY ADDRESS={{proxy}}";

iimSet("proxy","1.1.1.1:8000")
iimPlay(mainmacro )
```

Comment: I had tried something similar to this, that does the same thing. Pinterest was still able to detect the change.

Comment: Then you have to put everything into 1 macro. I will edit the example.

Comment: I wish I could, but I can not. The java script hold data to use and a counter. We load a block of macro code with specific values. I would send you the code but it is very dear to us and best kept private.

Comment: Contact me via my profile. There is a website there.